Serverless lambda deploy with container image, getting The image manifest or layer media type for the source image not supported error
I'm deploying a simple python function using serverless deploy , I was able to do so earlier but when I updated my docker, I started getting this error:
The image manifest or layer media type for the source image <>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/serverless-serverless-lab-dev@sha256:## is not supported.
I have checked that my docker image is not using multi arch and have specified the architecture in the serverless.yml file as well, but I still keep getting this error.
service: serverless-lab
provider:
  name: aws
  ecr:
    scanOnPush: true
    images:
      appimage: 
        path: ./
        file: Dockerfile
        buildArgs:
          provenance: "false"
        platform: linux/amd64
iam:        
  role: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/serverlessRole
functions:
  first_function:
    image:
      name: appimage
      command:
        - handler.lambda_handler


I too have been getting this error. Some coworkers were as well, but not all of them.
On ECR the artifact type turns into "image index" instead of being just "image", which I think is one of the key issues causing the error.
The docker files have ARCHITECTURE amd64 locally.
We added this to our CDK and it helped some, but didn't completely solve the issue:
code: DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(dockerfile, {
  platform: Platform.LINUX_AMD64,
}),

I believe Docker Desktop has started making the manifests include more than just the define platform, even if it's "not supported". I think that turns the "image" type into a "image index" type. I'm not sure the fix, or if that's actually the issue.
Something that worked for a bit was to roll back Docker Desktop to pre 4.30.0, but even with check for updates unchecked, Docker Desktop continues to update every day for us.
Good luck on your quest, I hope we both figure out the path forward!
